# How can I filter a SharePoint list based on a date column?

Tags: list, filter

I have a column with "start date".
I also have a column called "expire date".

How can I make a filtered list so that it only shows items where the "start date" is equal or greater
and 
equal or greater than "expire date"?

I have tried to use "start date" == [Today]
OR
"expira date" == [Today]

Doesnt work in SharePoint 2007. Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create/modify a view and apply the filter on the start date. To create/modify a view, go to list settings-> Scroll down to bottom and you will see a section named Views. Here you can click on exiting view or create a new view. In the view you can filter based on the start date in the Filter Section.

**UPDATE**

Based on your update in the question. This is how you can approach it. Create a Calculated column "DateDifference" and use the follwing formula [StartDate]-[ExpireDate] and have it return a number. Now the number can be either negative, zero or positive. Then put a filter based on this new column which will be like "DateDifference" is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: The filter command [Today] works with this but I want the list to be seen for a bit longer period.

Comment: You can add or subtract days from [Today] something like [Today]+3 or [Today]-3

Comment: Damn... Was kind of hoping that in stead of [Today] I could use [start date] or [expire date]. Values from those fields are what I need...

Comment: See my update. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

its long winded but,, you need to add a filterd webpart to the list page:

this is a step by step guide with images!

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-date-range.aspx

[image]

Comment: This post has almost no information in it. The link does not seem to work today.