# Using Lookup field but removing some items

Tags: lookup-column, filter, date

We're creating a sign up list for our fortnightly inductions at work. We've got a list which has all the induction dates, and another list for the signups.

The signups list has a lookup field to the date column of the induction date list. This then enables us to display the list of signups for the induction on the dispform of the particular induction date.

What I'd like to do is get SharePoint to automatically not display past induction dates in the lookup field. I was hopeing there would be something similar to how in views you can filter by date being > [today]

I know we could just delete past dates manually, but I'd like to remove human error as much as possible.

Comment: have a read of this post for some ideas at how to do this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84853/how-can-i-filter-a-sharepoint-list-based-on-a-date-column

Comment: Thank-you but that thread only has solutions to do this for a view, I'm wanting to do it for a lookup field. (To prevent users signing up for past dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this issue here is how I solved it:

Create a new single line of text column called [Time Title]

Create a work flow on item creation:

- Update [Time title] in current item to [Title]
- Pause until date = [date]
- Update [Time title] in current item to ""

Then I changed my key Lookup field to be "Time Title", and the blank ones are automatically removed. This allows us to keep a list of all dates, requires no human input (outside of the initial data entry) and prevents users from registering for past inductions